# Detect if Shell Flyout is open

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

Is there any way to handle opening Flyout?
I'm trying to add custom behavior during opening or after opening Flyout.

I can;t find any type of propety like
`Shell.OnFlyoutOpening="flyout_opening"`

Answer (score 6):

Since there is no and won't be events such `OnFlyoutOpened` `OnFlyoutClosed`, you can listen to your Shell `PropertyChanged` event, if the property is [FlyoutIsPresented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.shell.flyoutispresented?view=xamarin-forms) then execute your code:

```
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PropertyChanged += Shell_PropertyChanged;
}

private void Shell_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals("FlyoutIsPresented"))
        if (FlyoutIsPresented)
            OnFlyoutOpened();
        else
            OnFlyoutClosed();
}
```

Depending on your requirement you will define `OnFlyoutOpened()` and `OnFlyoutClosed()` methods.

Thanks to @PureWeen guidance in [discussion](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12682).